# How to put black color in the bottom of the page after footer

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to put a black color of half inch in the bottom of the aspx page after(below) footer.

I tried

css

```
#footerCol
{
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

html :

```
<div id="footerCol"> </div>
```

Comment: `border-bottom: 20px solid #000` ? there's no such thing as an inch in web development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use border-top

```
#footerCol{
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/V6UEL/

Comment: Can you explain better what you need? maybe upload an image as reference.

Comment: I want to draw a horizontal black thick line..the one in this stackoverflow page.

Answer (score 1):

when you said "after", I thought you meant "after":-

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>answer</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
        }
        #footerCol {
            color: #999;
            padding: 10px 0;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: normal;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: .9em;
        }
            #footerCol::after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
                background-color: black;
                height: 20px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="footerCol">
        footer text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to draw a black horizontal thick line to the page. Like the one in this stackoverflow page.

Comment: I've added a body {margin:0;} to remove the white space around the block.