# change the color of the remaining part after footer to (footer color / black) - bootstrap

Tags: html, css

[image: View the image]

How can I change the color of that part to something else? I want that to be the same color as footer color.
How can I do that?
what css or html code do I need?
I am using bootstrap 3.
already tried :
[How to put black color in the bottom of the page after footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600520/how-to-put-black-color-in-the-bottom-of-the-page-after-footer)
that does not work for me.

my html of _Layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                HEADER<div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                sidebar
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
                </div>

            </div>




            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    content1
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    content2
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>






        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    FOOTER

                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>





            <hr />

            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

        </div>
    </div>



    <footer class="navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class=”row bottom-rule”>


                <div class="col-sm-4 footer-section">
                    <strong>Connect with Best Store</strong>
                    <p>Email promotions, news, and information</p>
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only"
                                   for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                            <input type="email"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   id="inputEmail"
                                   placeholder="address@example.com">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 footer-section">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="text-uppercase">Customer Service:</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Guarantee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shipping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product Guides</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="text-uppercase">Social Media &amp; Articles:</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pinterest</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">The Best Journal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="text-uppercase">Events:</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hangout April 30</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Makers Faire</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <address>
                        <strong>Best Store</strong><br>
                        1000 Some Fantastic Place<br>
                        San Francisco, CA 94103<br>
                        (123) 456-7890 (phone &amp; text)<br>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </address>
                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="row bottom-rule">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-footer">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Summer Lookbook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Best Store</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">The Best Journal</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->



            <div class="row leg-room">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="text-uppercase">Best Store</h1>
                    <p class="monospaced">
                        &copy;2016 Best Store Company Inc.
                        <span class="text-uppercase">All Rights Reserved</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->


        </div><!-- end container -->
    </footer>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Site.css:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}



/* my */
.bottom-rule {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-top: 10px solid #332e20;
    background-color: white;
}

.footer-section {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
 }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .footer-section {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-bottom: none;
     }
 }

footer .list-inline li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.navbar-footer {
    background-color: inherit;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-footer {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

footer .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.leg-room { margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; }

.monospaced { font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospaced ; }
```

using visual studio 2015.

PS: I don't want to change the color of the background of the body to black! – user2548663 7 secs ago

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the background of the body to black!

Comment: i think it would be ok if you create a div after footer and give it height and background color.

Comment: that didn't solve it!

Comment: Well then how about you first find out what element it actually _is_ in that position? (Browser dev tools help.) If there isn’t an extra element, but that _is_ just part of the body showing there, then you would need to insert an additional element that can be formatted separately at that position first. (Unless you can perhaps emulate the same effect using a colored border or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color of the body to black:

In your css change:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the color of the background of the body to black!

Comment: That IS the answer to your question though. The Container you have in your HTML will set the color of the background WITH content to the correct color. Please try the solution provided before denouncing it. Happy yo help.